# Sur les temps verbaux utilisés avec l'expression « à peine ... que »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, temps-grammatical

En anglais, l'expression homologue, *no sooner ... than*, a une forme fixe, qui est presque idiomatique : *no sooner + past perfect simple, than + past tense simple*.

Je ne sais pas si en français *à peine ... que* a une forme fixe aussi. Tout ce que j'en sais est que le verbe utilisé après *à peine* est à l'imparfait, selon [cette source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/%C3%A0-peine-que) :

> À peine venait-il d'emménager qu'il dut entreprendre des travaux.

ou au passé antérieur, selon [cette source](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/peine/59016/difficulte):

> À peine la jeune femme fut-elle arrivée que...

N'y a-t-il en français une forme fixe comme celle qu'on trouve en anglais ?

Comment: No sooner do you ask such a question than someone points out that it's not fixed in English either (even if it may appear in that configuration most often).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I.** Les deux sont possibles. Les sources que tu cites donnent des exemples, elles ne donnent pas de règle sur l'emploi de l'imparfait ou du passé antérieur après *à peine*.

> - À peine la jeune femme fut-elle arrivée qu'il se mit à pleuvoir.
> - À peine la jeune femme arrivait-elle qu'il se mit à pleuvoir.

Des exemples en littérature (donc non fabriqués pour l'usage d'un dictionnaire) :

> À peine arrivaient-ils par la rue du Pas-de-la-Mule, aux grilles de la place déserte, qu'ils aperçurent sous l'arcade, au débouché de la rue Sainte-Catherine, trois cavaliers. (Alexandre Dumas, *Vingt ans après*).

> ...à peine furent-ils arrivés à cent lieues de leur pays,[...] à Brixen sur la frontière d’Italie, que Munch [...] dit à son ami ... (Stendhal, *Mémoires d’un Touriste*, II)

À partir de ton autre exemple :

> - À peine venait-il d'emménager qu'il dut entreprendre des travaux.
> - À peine eut-il emménagé qu'il dut entreprendre des travaux.
> - À peine emménageait-il qu'il dut entreprendre des travaux.

À propos de ce dernier cas : à noter que *venir de* ne pourrait pas se mettre au passé antérieur, je ne connais pas de « règle » à ça (il en existe peut-être une), est-ce tout simplement à cause de son sens ? Parfois considéré comme un auxiliaire (on dit que c'est un « semi-auxiliaire ») *venir de* sert à indiquer un passé récent.

**II.** Ceci dit y a-t-il une différence de sens si l'on emploie l'un ou l'autre temps avec  *à peine...que*  (parce que bien sûr passé antérieur et imparfait ne sont pas toujours interchangeables.

Je vais essayer d'en trouver une.
Une des valeurs de l'**imparfait** est de marquer une action en train de se faire et permet de mettre en valeur la **durée de l'action**.
Le passé antérieur indique une action passée, **à un moment précis**, et par rapport à une autre action qui est exprimée au passé simple. On le trouve essentiellement dans des subordonnées de temps après une conjonction de temps qui indique la postériorité (*Dès que, aussitôt que, après que*...).
En suivant cette voie je me hasarde à dire que l'emploi de l'imparfait montrerait l'action encore en cours alors que le passé antérieur indiquerait une action achevée.
Prenons nos deux exemples de départ :

> À peine la jeune femme arrivait-elle qu'il se mit à pleuvoir.

→ Elle était encore sur le pas de la porte, elle n'avait pas encore refermé la porte quand il s'est mis à pleuvoir.

> À peine la jeune femme fut-elle arrivée qu'il se mit à pleuvoir.

→ Elle était déjà entièrement à l'intérieur et peut-être avait-elle déjà enlevé ses chaussures quand il s'est mis à pleuvoir.

Peut-être que certains trouveront que c'est une explication un peu tirée par les cheveux, pour l'heure je n'en vois pas d'autre.

**III.** Ceci dit, bien sûr, comme en anglais (cf. @LukeSawczak's comment), on peut trouver d'autres temps que l'imparfait ou le passé antérieur dans une subordonnée introduite par *à peine*.

> À peine me suis-je réveillé, que j'ai allumé la bouilloire.

→ Nous avons là deux actions au passé composé.

> À peine poses-tu une question que tu as dix réponses.

→ Nous avons là deux actions au présent.

Comment: Before reading OP’s question and your good answer to it, the first line of Mr. Corneille’s [*L'amour naissant*](http://triptyques.blogspot.com/2009/05/la-beaute-de-lamourhttpwwwbloggercompos.html) («À peine je vous vois, que mes frayeurs cessées [l]aissent évanouir l'image du trépas.») used to be just one of my favorite lines of poetry, but now it’s also one of my favorite examples of «à peine» introducing present actions!

Comment: "Les sources que tu cites [...] ne donnent pas de règle sur l'emploi de l'imparfait ou du passé antérieur après à peine". Hence my question.

Comment: @User26328 I got why you asked the question, I gather I was reacting to your wording " le verbe utilisé après à peine est à l'imparfait, selon  cette source .. ou au au passé antérieur, selon cette source...". To me (I may be wrong) it sounded as if you were thinking one of the two was wrong and you were looking for a rule. I'm a bit a nit-picker where language is concerned, I know I can get annoying at times.

Comment: Since they are given as examples of good French in prestigious dictionaries, I imagined none could be wrong. But without any attempt at a certain systematization, I got confused: when, I thought to myself, should I use one and when the other? Confusion is never good, especially that I am, too, something of a nit picker myself when it comes to wordland.

Comment: @User26328 "prestigious dictionaries" Larousse, especially online, not really, and as far as **good** is concerned **my** own personal opinion is that I won't trust it.   Once you master French enough a good all French dictionary is the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/), in my opinion it is more reliable, with more in context examples. Have you tried it yet? The way you ask your questions makes me think you could try it.  You might be approaching C1 level.